# Automation testing framework for webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, testing, automation

I am new to VS( about 6 months), we have an application built using WCF and I am looking for some pointer to build a automation framework around it.

I tried with soap UI but its too simple for my application, any suggestions/pointers where and how should I start building this framework( only option I see here is Nunit.

here is my requirement, I am looking more of step by step guide to achieve this

A simple framework which will send some precooked input to the service and will have some expected value, this expected value will then matched against the actual value assert.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a good candidate for Visual Studio's Web & Load Test feature. I personally use these to test WCF endpoints frequently. You can either record steps using your browser, or write code that consumes your service. Either way, it functions just as a normal unit test does.

Comment: I am fairly new to C#, to start with I am looking for some thing where I would simply send a request to my web service ( for that I have xml inputs to be sent) and assert the response recieved from the web service. Any examples where this has been implemented would be great..